# how to keep open RadMenu on onclick event

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using radmenu in Master page.
when i try to click the radmenu item ,my radmenu get close.i want to open this radmenu even on click.

I searched some forums in telerik in which the people were saying set the `StaysOpenOnClick` property to True.

when i try to set the `StaysOpenOnClick` property ,that property is not showing in property box of radmenu control.

Means I am not able to find the `StaysOpenOnClick` property in control.

Can you pls provide the solution for this issue.

What I have done ,

```
 <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu3" runat="server" ClickToOpen="true"    >  
                       <Items>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="User Reminder" Selected="true" ImageUrl="../Images/todo.png" PostBack="false" Value="1" BackColor="#5872A6" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1em" ToolTip="User Reminders">
                            <Items>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem PostBack="false" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style=" width:400px;" >
                            <ucProviderReminder:ProviderReminder ID="ProviderReminder" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                       </Items>
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                       </Items>
                     </telerik:RadMenu>
```

Comment: Respond something Friend  , Is my answer useful for you or not ?

Comment: any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ClickToOpen="true"` in your RadMenu Property . For Example ,

```
  <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="40px"   
   EnableRoundedCorners="True"  ClickToOpen="true" >
```

**OR**

This is client side javascript function to open and close RadMenu , it's just an example .
But you can reference this . In this code , it's has two buttons , `open` and `close` .
And you can see , if user click `open` , the radmenu item with given value will open ,  it will stay , will not collapse until `mouse over`  and until click `close` button .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function OpenItem()
    {
        var menu = $find("RadMenu1");
        var text = $get("openTextBox").value;

        var item = menu.findItemByText(text);

        if (item)
        {
            item.open();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Item with text '" + text + "' not found.");
        }
    }

    function CloseItem()
    {
        var menu = $find("RadMenu1");
        var text = $get("closeTextBox").value;

        var item = menu.findItemByText(text);

        if (item)
        {
            item.close();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Item with text '" + text + "' not found.");
        }
    }
 </script>


    <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadows="true">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Corporate">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="About us">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Careers">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Services">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Products">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Solutions">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Certifications">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Work">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Clients">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Testimonials">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="FAQ">
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenu>


      Item to open: &nbsp;<input type="text" id="openTextBox" value="Corporate" class="textfield"
                style="vertical-align: top;" />
            <button class="button" onclick="OpenItem();return false;" style="width: 70px">
                Open</button><br />
            Item to close:
            <input type="text" id="closeTextBox" value="Corporate" class="textfield" style="vertical-align: top;" />
            <button class="button" onclick="CloseItem();return false;" style="width: 70px">
                Close</button><br />
```

Comment: Hi zey!!First thank you for your response.                            i have used ClickToOpen property.ClickToOpen property is used to specify that menu items do not expand when the mouse hovers over them until the user clicks the menu with the mouse.in my RadmenuItem i have taken Item Template and in this Item Template i have taken UserControl.in user control there is div which has click event.when i clicked on div Radmenu get close.

Answer (score -1):

The StaysOpenOnClick property is available on the RadMenuItem and not the RadMenu. See if setting the StaysOpenOnClick  on the RadMenuItem works in you case.

```
    <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu3" runat="server" ClickToOpen="true"    >
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" Text="User Reminder" Selected="true" ImageUrl="../Images/todo.png" PostBack="false" Value="1" BackColor="#5872A6" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1em" ToolTip="User Reminders" >
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadMenuItem PostBack="false" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div style=" width:400px;" >
                                                <ucProviderReminder:ProviderReminder ID="ProviderReminder" runat="server" />
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                                </Items>
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenu>
```